restore closed Finder window (after Mac restart)
I have multiple Finder windows opened, one of them having a set of important tabs/locations opened. By mistake, I closed that window.
How can I restore it?
I noticed some applescripts, but I don't know to work with them; I read about Go > Recent folders but the list is filled with other folders/locations which I open but are not so important.
I tried restarting with this setting uncheked "Close windows when quitting an app" but the Finder does not have the tabs I'm interested. (yes, I'd restarted my mbp and no I'm in deeper problem than before)
